# Python parameter behavior

Tags: python, parameters, namedtuple

My understanding of function parameters in Python is that they are like empty objects until function call and that's it. eg.

```
def square(x): #where x is an empty var defined here.
    return x*x #for the scope of this function
```

So how does this work, where "NamedTuple" is a callback function I assume? Does "NamedTuple" return value gets used as the parameter to class Car()?

```
>>> from typing import NamedTuple

>>> class Car(NamedTuple):
...     color: str
...     mileage: float
...     automatic: bool

>>> car1 = Car("red", 3812.4, True)

>>> # Instances have a nice repr:
>>> car1
Car(color='red', mileage=3812.4, automatic=True)
```

Comment: `class Foo(something)` isn't a function (it's a class definition) and `something` isn't a parameter (it's an inheritance list). I'm voting to close as a misunderstanding/unhelpful to future visitors; see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

Comment: I suggest you read more about classes and inheritence. There is no function call here.

Comment: Coming from javascript? In Python, "class" is a core part of the language rather than syntatic sugar.

Comment: @PaulBecotte Yes I'am! Thank you took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

`class Car(NamedTuple):` is a class declaration, not a function call. `NamedTuple` is a class that `Car` is derived from.

Answer (score 0):

No, `NamedTuple` is not a function, but a class. This is called **inheritance** (or subclassing), more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp).